# Drools decision table with contains operator in a conditional group not working

Tags: drools

Drools 6.2Final

i am using a Decision Table with the following expression

```
<row 10> CONDITION
<row 12> classList $param
```

with rows containing

```
<row 43> (contains('AAA') || contains('BBB') ) && contains('CCC') <--fails to compile
<row 44> (contains('AAA') || contains('BBB') 
<row 45> (contains('AA') || contains('BB') || contains('CCC') || contains('DDD')
```

where the fact classList is

```
List<String> classList = {'AAA', 'BB'.....}
```

the rule43 is meant to fire if the list contains either 'AAA' OR 'BBB' AND 'CCC'

however the decision table parser is failing with exception for rule 43

```
[Error: Missing left node]
[Near : {... classList (contains("AAA") || contains("CCC")) ....}]
```

i have a similar rule working fine for other rows

```
<row 42> contains('AAA') || contains('BBB') || contains('CCC')
```

there seems to be something strange with using the contains operator in a group condition. Any ideas on how the correct expression?

thanks

-lp

Comment: What is the fact type? classList? What is its list field name? What are you entering in the cells below to replace `$param`? - You can't use *any* binary operator without a left operand - this is certainly not "strange".

Comment: @laune i edited my question to answer your questions. the classList is list<String> and the rules are the grouped 'contains'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table entries don't look right to me, and you have not shown the Java code for `classList` - the explanation "is `List<String>`" is rather ambiguous.

The following condition entry works fine (5.5.0), if facts of class `List<Integer>` are inserted:

```
CONDITION
List
this (contains $1 || contains $2) && contains $3
match some funny numbers
42, 142, 100
```

If the list is field `intList` in class `SomeClass`, you can use

```
CONDITION
SomeClass
intList (contains $1 || contains $2) && contains $3
match some funny numbers
42, 142, 100
```

Note: I'm showing the top four rows for a column plus one row to trigger the creation of a rule.

**EDIT** to show that another variant is working:

```
CONDITION
$x: Country()
cities $param
match values in a List
(contains 'Rome' || contains 'Milan') && contains 'Naples'
```

The compiled rule is

```
rule "match cities"
when
    $x: Country(cities (contains 'Rome' || contains 'Milan') && contains 'Naples')
then
    //...
end
```

It's annoying that you can't use quotes (") to delimit the string literals, but apostrophes work.

If this doesn't work in 6.2.0, it's a regression and you should report a bug on Drools JIRA.

As a workaround, consider separating the conjunction and disjunction:

```
CONDITION                           | CONDITION
                $x: Country()
cities $param                       | cities $param
alternatives                        | alternatives
contains 'Rome' || contains 'Milan' | contains 'Naples'
```

Note that the second row has joined cells! The resulting DRL should be

```
rule "match cities"
when
    $x: Country(cities contains 'Rome' || contains 'Milan', cities contains 'Naples')
then
    //...
end
```

Comment: you misinterpreted my question. i clearly didnt make my original question clear. the condition statement is only the first line ie. (classList $param). the rules themselves has the operand AND values to match in each row as there are arbitrary number of values to match against. ie it is not simply 3 arguments to match for each rule. makes sense?